# How to migrate a zfs pool with minimal downtime?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, migration, zfs

I have a RAID1 ZFS pool with 2x 5TB mirrored and 2x 1TB mirrored drives and want to replace the two 1TB devices with 4TB ones. Since `zpool add` is undoable[1], it's necessary to destory the pool after having it recreated in the desired layout.

Therefore

- I `zpool detach`ed the mirrored devices and created a new pool with them.
- After the following commands failed because of overlapping mountpoints I ex- and re-imported it with an alternative root using `zpool import -R /mnt/data1`
- I created a snapshot `migrate1` in order to be able to run `sudo zfs send -R data@migrate1 | sudo zfs receive -F data1` which is currently in progress.

Now, I'd like to know the best proceedure after the `zfs send` pipe completed since in my understanding I have to get the old pool `data` to mount at an alternative root and the new pool `data1` without an alternative root after the reboot in order to be able to delete the old pool and make its device available for attaching to the new one. Maybe there's another way.

I'm using ZFS 0.7.0-182_gc0daec32f8 and SPL 0.7.0-20_g35a44fcb built from source on Ubuntu 17.10 with Linux 4.13.0-16-generic.

I checked

- [Can I safely migrate a ZFS pool from FreeBSD to Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/577558/can-i-safely-migrate-a-zfs-pool-from-freebsd-to-ubuntu) which is about Ubuntu vs. FreeBSD format whereas I remain on the same Ubuntu
- [Migrate LVM to ZFS](https://superuser.com/questions/696948/migrate-lvm-to-zfs) which doesn't have the same problems like overlapping mountpoints and the need for `ALTROOT`

I know that this is complicated and that it wouldn't hurt to keep the 1TB devices inside the pool, but that's not part of the question.

---

[1] I requested this as ZFSOnLinux issue at https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/6857 which provides links to the complex plan/roadmap behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a RAID1 ZFS pool with 2x 5TB mirrored and 2x 1TB mirrored drives and want to replace the two 1TB devices with 4TB ones. Since zpool add is undoable[1], it's necessary to destory the pool after having it recreated in the desired layout.

This sounds more like striped mirrors (2x2) than RAIDZ1 (at least 3x1). Either way, you can grow both configurations in place by removing and replacing one disk at a time. Wait for each resilver to finish, then replace the next disk. Finally, after all disks have been replaced, `zpool offline` the pool and then `zpool online -e` it to expand to the new size (or set `autoexpand=true` before expansion):

```
    zpool online [-e] pool device...
         Brings the specified physical device online. This command is not
         applicable to spares.

         -e      Expand the device to use all available space. If the
                 device is part of a mirror or raidz then all devices must
                 be expanded before the new space will become available to
                 the pool.
```

You would of course first re-attach the detached devices in your case, because replacement is only possible when there is sufficient redundancy.

---

Aside from that, you can set and change mountpoints on the fly, and you can destroy pools with active mountpoints (as long as there is no active I/O on them). If it does not work, `zpool export`/`zpool import` does most of the time, as does a reboot (if you can allow one, and this is not the root pool).

Comment: I meant RAID1 (!= RAIDZ1) in the sense of mirroring without parity or striping. This answer is correct, unfortunately, I asked an XY question leaving out a crucial details which makes this solution not work for me.

Comment: @KarlRichter Sorry, I misread the Z1 part. You also could edit your question and include additional details so the answers (mine and others) could be more helpful to you.